# When I create an If statement with multiple requirement some of it is working and other half isn't

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am hoping this will be a very quick fix for some of you experts out there, but I have searched and searched and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Essentially my goal is to have multiple sheets hide and unhide based on various values in other sheets and cells. If a user selects a certain combination of "Yes" and "No" questions on the first sheet, a selected second sheet will appear. And when they input a value in the second sheet, a third sheet will appear. I have been able to work out all of this fine, my problem is when the questions on the first sheet change the third sheet remains visible, but I want the third sheet to become hidden without the user having to change the information on the second sheet that made it visible in the first place.

This is my code for my first sheet (which works fine)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [C5] = "Yes" _
And [C6] = "No" _
And [C7] = "No" Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

And this is my code for the second sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If [H11] > 0 Or [H12] > 0 Or [H13] > 0 _
And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value = "Yes" _
And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6").Value = "No" _
And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value = "No" Then
Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

The first half of the code is working, but the portion of the code that references a cell in a different sheet does not work. I have tried multiple ways of formatting the references and nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Who calls `Sub_Worksheet`, how do you know that "references a cell in a different sheet does not work", and what does it mean that they do not work?

Comment: Firstly, your code does not use `Target` at all. It should limit the event action to the range "C6:C7". Then, if you want a sheet to be hidden, **your code must hide it**. In your case it  the third sheet is hidden only if the `IF` conditions are not met... you probably lost some letters form `Sub_Worksheet`. Shouldn't it be`Sub Worksheet_change` event?

Comment: Sorry, the "sub_worksheet" is a typo from when I copied it over. It is "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" and I have made that edit. When I run the code and input values for H11, H12, or H13 it hides sheet 3 as it should, but when I change the values in sheet one (C5, C6, and C7) it does not hide sheet 3, which is why I think it is the second portion that references a cell in a different sheet that is not working.

Comment: Maybe you want to check if you need some brackets. Mixing `Or` and `And` is sometimes tricky

Comment: My money is on Ike being correct but you have not defined "working" : we need example conditions of inputs and expected results. What conditions should trigger hidden vs visible.  We cannot tell from your code bc it begs the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

`And` takes precedence over `Or`

```
A or B and C
```

Is the same as

```
A or (B and C)
```

If A is true, the result is true and B and C are irrelevant

Adding parenthesis will reduce confusion especially when Or is involved.